# JavaScript: Initializing inner variable after initializing object

Tags: javascript, object, scope, closures, delayed-execution

*Update: rewriting question because original question had false assumptions (I was running code in a console that had already initialized the variables I thought were undefined).*

This makes sense:

```
var obj = { 'whichScope': a };
obj.whichScope; //"ReferenceError: a is not defined"
```

But then how come this next example doesn't throw an error? And if the second line is getting run before the first line, why doesn't obj.whichScope resolve to "After"?

```
var obj = { 'whichScope': a };
var a = "After";
obj.whichScope; //"undefined"
```

If "var a" in the previous example runs before obj is initialized, does any part of 'a = "After";' also run before obj is initialized?

```
var a = "Before";
var obj = { 'whichScope': a };
a = "After";
obj.whichScope; //"Before"
```

If whichScope refers to a function that returns 'a' then it does resolve to "After" in the last example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called variable hoisting.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting
- http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/

Variables (declared with `var`) and functions are hoisted to the top of their scope.

So technically, your script is like this:

```
var a;  // = undefined
var obj = { 'whichScope': a };
a = "After";
```

Although your first example doesn't do what you say. The value of `obj.whichScope` is `undefined`, as expected.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pRQwK/

As for your last statement, `If whichScope refers to a function that returns 'a' then it does resolve to "After" in the second example.` - that is because the value of `a` isn't captured (by a closure). When setting a property, its value is captured immediately (unrelated to a closure).